# Check if all values of keys of multidimentionnal array are numeric?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

i'm gona crazy, debuting in php..

I need to check if key value of an multidimentionnal array are all numeric..

a print_r() of my $values_arr give that:

```
Array ( [coco] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 99 ) [chanel] => 150
```

I need to check if 18 and 99 and 150 are numeric, i will don't know what will in the array , and this array will not more 2 dimention.

I tryed many things, the last one..:

```
foreach ( $values_arr as $foo=>$bar ) { 

 if(  !in_array( $foo, $_fields_arr )  || !is_numeric($bar ) ) {

                        echo "NOTGOOD";   

                 } 
                 }




                          ****UPDATE****
```

new test :Here because chanel isnot int , this exemple should be echo "not goud",
but its not the case..

```
$_fields_arr = array('coco','chanel','other');                                

$ary = array(
  'coco' => array(18, 99),
  'chanel' => 'yu'
);


function allIntValues($o)
{
  if (is_int($o)) return true;
  if (is_array($o)){
    foreach ($o as $k => $v) {
      if (!is_int($v)) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

foreach ($ary as $k => $v) {
  if (!in_array($k, $_fields_arr) || !@allIntValues($v)){

echo "notgood";

 }

  else echo "good";
}
```

thanks for any help,
 regards

Comment: What do you mean "numeric"? Are you refering to a datatype (int, float), or are strings representing nubers OK too?

Comment: int will be perfect..i ever tryed and !is_int() but i have always the same pb..

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
$ary = Array(
  'coco' => array(18, 99),
  'chanel' => 150
);
$_fields_arr = array('coco', 'chanel');

function allIntValues($o)
{
  if (is_int($o)) return true;
  if (is_array($o)){
    foreach ($o as $k => $v) {
      if (!is_int($v)) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

foreach ($ary as $k => $v) {
  if (in_array($k, $_fields_arr) && @allIntValues($v)){
    // $ary[$k] is no good
  }
}
```

---

Assuming you want to test if *all values* are numeric (despite how deep the value's nested):

```
function is_numeric_array($ary)
{
  foreach ($ary as $k => $v)
  {
    if (is_array($v))
    {
      if (!is_numeric_array($v))
        return false;
    }
    else if (!is_numeric($v))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

That will (recursively) check the array and make sure every value is numeric within the array.

```
array(1,2,3) // true
array('foo','bar','baz') // false ('foo', 'bar' & 'baz')
array(1,2,array(3,4)) // true
array(array(1,'foo'),2,3) // false (foo)
array("1,", "2.0", "+0123.45e6") // true
```

Comment: Please note, that [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) returns true even for strings representing numbers

Comment: I have to keep my foreach ( $values_arr as $foo=>$bar ) { 

 if(  !in_array( $foo, $_fields_arr ) condition with it , actually it give me an error "Call to undefined function is_numeric_array()" , could you give me some concrete exemple for my case ?

Comment: @Erbureth: indeed. if this needs to be type sensitive you can also add checks for `is_int`/`is_double`

Comment: @albator: If you can provide the value of `$_fields_ary` and aht you're hoping for (some examples of what would pass and what would fail) I can provide a more concise answer.

Comment: $_fields_arr is a simple array ;$_fields_arr=array(bob,bub,bib,..) i use it to check if name is correct in the accepted list $_fields_arr

Comment: @albator: So it's an array of keys to verify essentially?

Comment: i need to chek if name is in $fields_arr and if all values of $values_arr key is int

Comment: i was thinking..is it not possible to count an array filter to doing the job ?! i'm too debutant lol, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are using the value instead of the key:

```
if(  !in_array( $bar, $_fields_arr )  || !is_numeric($foo ) ) {
```

Comment: i made mistake i think, i have to control the value of the key, in my explanation i was talking about control if 18, 99,150 are numeric

Comment: `$foo` is the key (`$key=>$value`)